# How to invert an image horizontally in python

Tags: python, image, parquet

I am loading images from a parquet file, and would like to know how to invert the right side of the image, and place it under the left side. I have attached the code to place the right side under the left, and would now like to invert the right before doing so. Thank you!

```
top = array[:,:13] # Take all rows until the 13th column
bottom = array[:,13:] # Take all rows after the 13th column
stacked = np.vstack([top,bottom]
```

Comment: @Marat Thank you!

Comment: I think I missed a semicolon in my comment and it's too late to edit: `bottom = array[:,:-13:-1] `

Comment: That gives me a shape of (10,13) on the top, and (10,12) for the bottom.

Comment: err, off-by-one, rather embarrassing. Should be `[:-14:-1]`